# Issue using 'inherit' with Tailwind CSS

Tags: next.js, jsx, tailwind-css

When I use the `inherit` property on a `<span>` it doesn't take the color of the parent, but it instead takes the color of the sibling.

My JSX:

```html
<div className={`relative flex items-center justify-center bg-blue-500`}>
    <span
        className={`bg-rose-600 border-4 border-inherit h-16 w-16 absolute top-1 rounded-full duration-500 ${Menus[active].dis}`}>
    </span>
    <div className={`bg-white max-h-[4.4rem] max-w-[360px] px-6 rounded-t-xl mt-6`}>
</div>
```

I want the `span` to take the blue color, not the white one.

I tried to put `important` on the `bg-color` of the parent, but that doesn't work.

Any ideas?

Comment: You are using `border-inherit`, but the parent doesn't have a border. If you try to inherit the background, you overdrive it with `bg-rose-600`. What exactly are you trying to do? Your explanation is somewhat confusing to understand.

Comment: I want that the border of the Child has the same color of the parent div

Comment: But the parent div doesn't have a border/border color. Are you trying to do something like this? https://play.tailwindcss.com/to0hWjaPwu

Comment: I understand my mistake sorry of course with a border-color of the parent it works ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing `border-color` in your parent:

```
<div class="... border-amber-400 ">  add border color here 
  <span class="border-inherit ... "> </span>
  <div class="... "></div>
</div>
```

Complete code:

```
<div class="relative flex items-center justify-center border-amber-400 bg-blue-500">
  <span class="absolute top-1 h-16 w-16 rounded-full border-4 border-inherit bg-rose-600 duration-500"> </span>
  <div class="mt-6 max-h-[4.4rem] max-w-[360px] rounded-t-xl bg-white px-6"></div>
</div>
```